# Story about people who take virtual trips using robots

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story about a young guy who has a job packing/unpacking  crt-tv tube box/robots which are virtual tourists. The tourists come across as being loud and rude.

I read this in the early 1970's.

Comment: Where did you read this, in which country? And also was it a collection or a magazine? What language was it in?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tourists who come across as loud and rude? As opposed to what?

Comment: This could be one of the parts to Michael G. Coney's "Friends Come in Boxes" from 1973, People ['friends'] waiting for new bodies are carted around in boxes while playing tourist. I don't have a copy to check for that specific character, although I recall a scene of the boxes with unhappy occupants being unloaded from a tour bus.

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents You should make that an answer. According to ISFDB, parts of [*Friends Come in Boxes*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3128) appeared as novelettes in *If*, namely ["The Never Girl"](https://archive.org/stream/1973-02_IF#page/n83/mode/2up) and ["A Woman and Her Friend"](https://archive.org/stream/1973-04_IF#page/n65/mode/2up) (links to the Internet Archive). Since the OP says "short story", maybe he read one of those.

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents: Would you like to pay your suggestion as an answer?